# Set discount for my app on Google Play

Tags: android, discount

I'd like help from people that published any apps on Google Play. I want to apply a 100% discount on my app for one week, which means it would be free during that time. However, I didn't see any way on the console to set that. If I try to put it free, it won't let me change back later. Is there any option I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: should this question be here in this site?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023668/what-if-i-change-my-android-app-price-to-free-and-after-i-change-idea

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Google Play.
However, what you could do is:

- release the app as free.
- lock some content in the up until the user has bought one inApp purchase (freemium mode).
- code logic for that content to be unlocked for the first week of use, and after that, lock the content and send the user to buy the inApp purchase in Google Play.